# Related to Lagrangian dual

Tags: linear-programming, duality, terminology, lagrange-multipliers, lagrangian-relaxation

In my research class our professor discuss a paper wherein the solution is obtained via a Lagrangian duality. The original problem is given below:

minimize $t$

subject to $\sum_{j \in \mathcal{M_i}}\beta_{ij}x_{ij}\leq t, i \in \mathcal{N}$ ---(1)

where $\mathcal{M_i}$ and $\mathcal{N}$ are the sets.

Next, a partial Lagrangian is obtained by dualizing the constraint in (1). To do this , the authors introduced multipliers $\lambda = (\lambda_i)_{i \in \mathcal{N}}$ for the first set of inequality constraints.

Thus, the partial Lagrangian is given by

$L(t, x, \lambda) = t(1-\sum_{i \in \mathcal{N}}\lambda_i)+\sum_{j \in \mathcal{M}}\sum_{i \in \mathcal{N_j}}\beta_{ij}\lambda_ix_{ij}$  ---(2)

where they used the equivalence of the following two sets

$\{(i,j)|i \in \mathcal{N}, j \in \mathcal{M_i}\}\equiv \{(n,m)|m \in \mathcal{M}, n \in \mathcal{N_m}\}$

I am not getting how equation (2) is obtained from equation (1).

Comment: Cross Posted on Math.SE:  [Related to Lagrangian dual](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4508798/572874)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dualizing a constraint comes back to the first, the direction of the objective function, and the second, how the dualized constraint would be violated. In your case, the constraint is written as $LHS-RHS \leq 0$, and therefore it is being violated when $LHS-RHS \geq 0$. Since we add this into the objective function as:
$$min \quad z = t + \sum_{i}\lambda_{i}(\sum_{j}\beta_{ij}x_{ij}-t) $$ by multiplying in the appropriate violation penalties as $\lambda_{i}$ as there exist $i$ number of such constraint.

Answer (score 2):

To ease notation, let me use B as (sum_j Beta_ij.x_ij).
Then the constraint (1) is B-t <=0... You multiply this with lambda_i (let me use L for short of sum_i Lambda_i) and carry to objective function, so new objective is:
t + L(B-t) = t-Lt + LB = t(1-L)+ LB

Comment: Thank you so much @Omidi ....but I am having a query that when in constraint only one summation is present then how second summation is also coming into picture...